# Memory inconsistency or thread interference or both?

Tags: java, multithreading

I got this code from Internet while reading about thread. It says it is an example of memory consistency error. Is it just memory inconsistency or thread interference that is producing the unexpected output? Why is it producing more positive values? It rarely outputs negative values.

```
class MemoryConsistencyError extends Thread {
    static int count = 0;
    public void run() {
        for (int x = 0; x < 1000000; x++) {
            count++;
            count--;
        }
        System.out.println(this.getName() + " count: " + count);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MemoryConsistencyError t1 = new MemoryConsistencyError();
        MemoryConsistencyError t2 = new MemoryConsistencyError();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure it will print more negative numbers if you swap the `count` line.

Comment: @MuratK. Still, the "why" has some merit ...

Comment: @MuratK. I was expecting the `count--` will overwrite the `count++` result during interference.

Comment: And for the record: this should show two threads working the same shared data in parallel. I do not see how that has *anything* to do with memory inconsistency.

Comment: @GhostCat That is my question. So, it is thread interference?

Comment: @bradimus can you explain why?

Comment: It is a typical example for a *race* condition. But I am busy thinking about the "why" part ;-)

Comment: It is also a typical example of a memory visibility problem: one thread could not see the changes made by the other one, because the count variable is not volatile.

Answer (score 0):

JLS chapter 17:

> Each action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order.

There are other cases for happens-before but none apply to code you posted (no `synchronize`, `start`ing or `join`ing threads or `volatile` in the code). Important point here is that happens-before from the quote applies for ONE THREAD. So, not your case, where you have TWO threads.

Ergo that's **NOT a broken happens-before guarantee** (which would indicate inconsistent memory), **merely thread interference**.

Thread interference is caused by the fact that every -- or ++ operation actually means THREE operations: read, in- or decrement and store. This is where operations of both threads overlap.

> Why is it producing more positive values? It rarely outputs negative values.

Because line order makes it easier to overwrite the store that happens with decrement than the one with increment. Thread interference makes you read stale data.

1. count is: read, increased, stored (`count++`)
2. count is: read, decreased, stored (`count--`)

Each STORE uses a value from it's READ. So, t1, reading 0, increases and stores 1. Same with t2. However t2 increase has great chances of overwriting t1 store after decrease. Not so the other way around.